# What's the difference between $query and $query_vars in global WP_Query

Tags: php, wordpress

From the [**docs**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Methods_and_Properties):

```
$query
Holds the query string that was passed to the $wp_query object by WP class.

$query_vars
An associative array containing the dissected $query: an array of the query variables and their respective values.
```

But when I do something like this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'post_status' => 'publish'
);
$author_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

then all these arguments go to `$query_vars` as I can see from `print_r($wp_query)` , so what's the purpose of `$query` here and how can I adjust the value of this property.

I'm curious because when I go to author template the `query` property inside this page contains something like `[author_name] => admin`?

Answer (score 2):

`$query` is an array with the values passed when `WP_Query` is called, your custom values.

`$query_vars` is an array with all the parameters supported by `WP_Query`, including the parameters usen when `WP_Query` was called and the rest of the parameters with the default value.

edit: The reason you are seeing the `author_name` set is that Wordpress gets the value from the URL, but you could pass it using a custom query or some filter. When Wordpress detects that parameter in the url, automagically matches the right template, you could see how that works in the [template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy)

Comment: It's actually the opposite. `$query` contains the original _raw_ parameters and `$query_vars` contains the _parsed_ parameters.
The former contains only the parameters you passed, and those extracted by the URI, and the latter contains all variables with undefined ones filled in empty.

Comment: The answer is fixed now.